# Incoming email account not correct ERROR”

Tags: erpnext, frappe

> How to set up email account in erp next i tried to setup email but
> Incoming email account not correct ERROR” and Email Domain not
> accepted
> [want to setup email account for erpnext via simple gmail account in gmail access for less secure app is also checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzQt8.jpg)

Comment: I guess its a typo in "imap.gmai.com", correct one is pop.gmail.com, you missed l from gmail

Comment: Hi @Vishal Patil i am also facing this issue. have you found any solution.